# ¿Por qué no se rellenan las variables de mi base de datos al cargar datos de excel?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, composer

Resulta que estoy haciendo una tabla que al ingresarle la información que tengo en un Excel, esta cargue mi base de datos. El problema es que estuve usando de guía el siguiente video [Cargar Excel a la BD Mysql - Parte 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km8ElaTAi5k&t=6s) En el, al finalizar todo el proyecto, sí almacena los datos que tengo en mi Excel a la tabla "categorías", pero la tabla "productos" no se carga en mi base de datos, me la deja completamente vacía.

Otro error que me genera mi código es que al cargarse los datos de mi excel a mi base de datos, en vez de arrojarme el mensaje de  "Se registraron 19 categorías y 300 productos", me arroja el mensaje de ""Se presento un error al momento de realizar el registro"

A qué se debe esto? Si seguí al pie de la letra el video. Qué debería  modificar para poder que se pueda cargar correctamente mi tabla "productos" a mi mysql?

Estoy usando composer, php y mysql. El githud del archivo esta subido [aquí](https://github.com/Luison84/sistema-pos).

HTML:

```
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">Carga Masiva de Productos</h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Carga Masiva de Productos</li>
                    </ol>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- FILA PARA INPUT FILE -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card card-info">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Seleccionar Archivo de Carga (Excel):</h3>
                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div> <!-- ./ end card-tools -->
                        </div> <!-- ./ end card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_carga_productos">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                        <input type="file" name="fileProductos" id="fileProductos" class="form-control"
                                            accept=".xls, .xlsx">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Cargar Productos" class="btn btn-primary"
                                            id="btnCargar">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
    
                        </div> <!-- ./ end card-body -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- FILA PARA IMAGEN DEL GIF -->
            <div class="row mx-0">
                <div class="col-lg-12 mx-0 text-center">
                    <img src="vistas/assets/imagenes/loading.gif" id="img_carga" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    
            $("#form_carga_productos").on('submit',function(e){
    
                e.preventDefault();
    
                /*===================================================================*/
                //VALIDAR QUE SE SELECCIONE UN ARCHIVO
                /*===================================================================*/
                if($("#fileProductos").get(0).files.length == 0){
                    Swal.fire({
                        position:'center',
                        icon:'warning',
                        title: 'Debe seleccionar un archivo (Excel).',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2500
                    })
                }else{
    
                    /*===================================================================*/
                    //VALIDAR QUE EL ARCHIVO SELECCIONADO SEA EN EXTENSION XLS O XLSX
                    /*===================================================================*/
                    var extensiones_permitidas = [".xls",".xlsx"];
                    var input_file_productos = $("#fileProductos");
                    var exp_reg = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\-.\:])+(" + extensiones_permitidas.join('|') + ")$");
    
                    if(!exp_reg.test(input_file_productos.val().toLowerCase())){
                        Swal.fire({
                            position:'center',
                            icon:'warning',
                            title: 'Debe seleccionar un archivo con extensión .xls o .xlsx.',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2500
                        })
    
                        return false;
                    }
    
                    var datos = new FormData($(form_carga_productos)[0]);
    
                    $("#btnCargar").prop("disabled",true);
                    $("#img_carga").attr("style","display:block");
                    $("#img_carga").attr("style","height:200px");
                    $("#img_carga").attr("style","width:200px");
    
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"ajax/productos.ajax.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: datos,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(respuesta){
    
                            // console.log("respuesta",respuesta);
    
                            if(respuesta['totalCategorias'] > 0 && respuesta['totalProductos'] > 0 ){
                            
                                Swal.fire({
                                    position:'center',
                                    icon:'success',
                                    title: 'Se registraron ' + respuesta['totalCategorias'] + ' categorías y ' + respuesta['totalProductos'] + 'productos correctamente!',
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500
                                })
    
                                $("#btnCargar").prop("disabled",false);
                                $("#img_carga").attr("style","display:none");
                            }else{
    
                                Swal.fire({
                                    position:'center',
                                    icon:'error',
                                    title: 'Se presento un error al momento de realizar el registro de categorías y/o productos!',
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500
                                })
    
                                $("#btnCargar").prop("disabled",false);
                                $("#img_carga").attr("style","display:none");
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
                }
            })
    
        })
    </script>
```

PRODUCTOS.AJAX.PHP

```
    <?php
    require_once "../controladores/productos.controlador.php";
    require_once "../modelos/productos.modelo.php";
    
    require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
    
    class ajaxProductos{
    
        public $fileProductos;
    
        public function ajaxCargaMasivaProductos(){
    
            $respuesta = ProductosControlador::ctrCargaMasivaProductos($this->fileProductos);
    
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
        }
    }
    
    if(isset($_FILES)){
        $archivo_productos = new ajaxProductos();
        $archivo_productos-> fileProductos = $_FILES['fileProductos'];
        $archivo_productos -> ajaxCargaMasivaProductos();
    }
```

PRODUCTOS.CONTROLADOR.PHP

```
<?php
    
    
    class ProductosControlador{
    
        static public function ctrCargaMasivaProductos($fileProductos){
            
            $respuesta = ProductosModelo::mdlCargaMasivaProductos($fileProductos);
            
            return $respuesta;
        }
    }
```

PRODUCTOS.MODELO.PHP

```
    <?php
    
    require_once "conexion.php";
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
    
    
    class ProductosModelo{
    
        static public function mdlCargaMasivaProductos($fileProductos){
    
            $nombreArchivo = $fileProductos['tmp_name'];
    
            $documento = IOFactory::load($nombreArchivo);
    
            $hojaCategorias = $documento->getSheet(1);
            $numeroFilasCategorias = $hojaCategorias->getHighestDataRow(); 
            
            $hojaProductos = $documento->getSheetByName("Productos");
            $numeroFilasProductos = $hojaProductos->getHighestDataRow();
    
            $categoriasRegistradas = 0;
            $productosRegistrados = 0;
    
            //CICLO FOR PARA REGISTROS DE CATEGORIAS
            for ($i=2; $i <= $numeroFilasCategorias ; $i++) { 
    
                $categoria = $hojaCategorias->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i);
                $aplica_peso = $hojaCategorias->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i);
                $fecha_actualizacion = date("Y-m-d");
    
                if(!empty($categoria)){
                    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO categorias(nombre_categoria,
                                                                                    aplica_peso,
                                                                                    fecha_actualizacion_categoria)
                                                                        values(:nombre_categoria,
                                                                                :aplica_peso,
                                                                                :fecha_actualizacion_categoria);");
    
                    $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre_categoria",$categoria,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt -> bindParam(":aplica_peso",$aplica_peso,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt -> bindParam(":fecha_actualizacion_categoria",$fecha_actualizacion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $categoriasRegistradas = $categoriasRegistradas + 1;
                    }else{
                        $categoriasRegistradas = 0;
                    }
                }            
                
            }
    
            if($categoriasRegistradas > 0){
    
                //CICLO FOR PARA REGISTROS DE PRODUCTOS
                for ($i=2; $i <= $numeroFilasProductos ; $i++) { 
    
                    $codigo_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("A".$i);
                    $id_categoria_producto = ProductosModelo::mdlBuscarIdCategoria($hojaProductos->getCell("B".$i));
                    $descripcion_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("C".$i);
                    $precio_compra_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("D".$i);
                    $precio_venta_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("E".$i);
                    $utilidad = $hojaProductos->getCell("F".$i);
                    $stock_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("G".$i);
                    $minimo_stock_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("H".$i);
                    $ventas_producto = $hojaProductos->getCell("I".$i);
                    $fecha_actualizacion_producto = date('Y-m-d');
    
                    if(!empty($codigo_producto)){
                        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO productos(codigo_producto,
                                                                                    id_categoria_producto,
                                                                                    descripcion_producto,
                                                                                    precio_compra_producto,
                                                                                    precio_venta_producto,
                                                                                    utilidad,
                                                                                    stock_producto,
                                                                                    minimo_stock_producto,
                                                                                    ventas_producto,
                                                                                    fecha_actualizacion_producto)
                                                                            values(:codigo_producto,
                                                                                    :id_categoria_producto,
                                                                                    :descripcion_producto,
                                                                                    :precio_compra_producto,
                                                                                    :precio_venta_producto,
                                                                                    :utilidad,
                                                                                    :stock_producto,
                                                                                    :minimo_stock_producto,
                                                                                    :ventas_producto,
                                                                                    :fecha_actualizacion_producto);");
    
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":codigo_producto",$codigo_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":id_categoria_producto",$id_categoria_producto[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":descripcion_producto",$descripcion_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":precio_compra_producto",$precio_compra_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":precio_venta_producto",$precio_venta_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":utilidad",$utilidad,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":stock_producto",$stock_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":minimo_stock_producto",$minimo_stock_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":ventas_producto",$ventas_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt -> bindParam(":fecha_actualizacion_producto",$fecha_actualizacion_producto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
                        if($stmt->execute()){
                            $productosRegistrados = $productosRegistrados + 1;
                        }else{
                            $productosRegistrados = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $respuesta["totalCategorias"] = $categoriasRegistradas;
            $respuesta["totalProductos"] = $productosRegistrados;
    
            return $respuesta;
        }
    
        static public function mdlBuscarIdCategoria($nombreCategoria){
    
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("select id_categoria from categorias where nombre_categoria = :nombreCategoria");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":nombreCategoria", $nombreCategoria,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
    
            return $stmt->fetch();
    
        }        
    }
```

CONEXION.PHP

```
    <?php
    class Conexion{
    
        static public function conectar(){
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=market-pos","root","",array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                return $conn;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Viste algo en los logs de PHP cuando intentas cargar los datos? Si lo hay, por favor ve a [edit] tu pregunta y añádelo EN la pregunta, igual que los bloques de código.